# How do you make non foreign key constraints in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using fluent nhibernate(v1.2) and nhibernate(v3.1) and I am having a weird Problem.

I have this

```
      public class GradeMap : ClassMap<Grade>
{
    public GradeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.GradeId);
        Map(x => x.TaskName).NvarcharWithMaxSize().Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Weight).Not.Nullable().Precision(5).Scale(2);
        Map(x => x.OutOf).Not.Nullable().Precision(5).Scale(2);
        Map(x => x.Mark).Not.Nullable().Precision(5).Scale(2);
        Map(x => x.CourseBackgroundColor).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.CoursePrefix).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Student).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Course);
    }
}

public class CourseMap : ClassMap<Course>
{
    public CourseMap()
    {

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("CourseId");
        Map(x => x.Prefix).NvarcharWithMaxSize().Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Tasks).Cascade.Delete().Inverse();
        HasMany(x => x.CoursePermissions).Cascade.All().Inverse();
        HasMany(x => x.CourseSharing).Cascade.All().Inverse();
        HasMany(x => x.Grades).Cascade.None().Inverse();
    }
}
```

I then do something like this

```
return session.Query<Grade>().ToList();
```

If I would try to grab a propety such as `Grade.Course.Id` it would crash and I would get.

```
Grade.Course = {Castle.Proxies.CourseProxy}
Grade.Course.Id = '((new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_CollectionDebugView<OnlGrade>(grades)).Items[0].Course).Id' threw an exception of type 'NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException'
Grade.Course.Prefix = above error except .Prefix instead of .Id
```

I would have thought Course Object would be empty or null. Not that it would have some Proxy with all properties throwing exceptions.

**Edit**

I found this posting but I don't have this attribute anymore so maybe they got rid of it or moved it.

Anyone know?

[Is it possible to avoid NHibernate.ObjectNotFoundException when there is a foreign key but the referenced row does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618615/is-it-possible-to-avoid-nhibernate-objectnotfoundexception-when-there-is-a-foreig)

Comment: Please, could you show full mapping for TableA and TableB, e.g. Id mapping is interesting. What version of NH and FNH do you use? What does it mean "If I do this TableA.TableB.Id..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about NotFound.Ignore()?

```
public class GradeMap : ClassMap<Grade>
{
    public GradeMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.GradeId);
        Map(x => x.TaskName).NvarcharWithMaxSize().Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Weight).Not.Nullable().Precision(5).Scale(2);
        Map(x => x.OutOf).Not.Nullable().Precision(5).Scale(2);
        Map(x => x.Mark).Not.Nullable().Precision(5).Scale(2);
        Map(x => x.CourseBackgroundColor).Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.CoursePrefix).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Student).Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Course)
            .NotFound.Ignore();
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Let's say database schema looks like this:

```
Grade(GradeId, TaskName, Course_id)
Course(CourseId, Prefix)
```

If there is no foreign key constraint on Course_id column, then row in Course table with CourseId that corresponds to Course_id column in Grade table can be deleted. E.g.:

```
Course table:
CourseId    Prefix
1           Course1Prefix

Grade table:
GradeId     TaskName    Course_id
1           Grade1Task  1
```

without foreign key constraint you can issue this dml query:

```
delete from Course where CourseId = 1
```

And it could be reason of problem explained by sJhonny.

When "NotFound.Ignore()" is used in the mapping then NHibernate tries to load Courses that belong to all Grades that were loaded by the query:

```
session.Query<Grade>().ToList();
```

No proxies are generated and when course referenced by grade is not found in database then the Course property is simply null.

If you can modify the database schema it would be helpful to create PK constraint on Course_id column.

Comment: Ya I found that as well but it did not solve my problem at hand. It's good to know. I am not sure what Nullable() is for then on References as I tried that and it was not very helpful.

Comment: References are nullable by default. What version of NH and FNH do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the error here is because you're accessing the Id property of an object which does not exist.
Do you get the same error if you do `TableA.TableB` ?

Comment: What do you mean with TableA.TableB? If you look at TableB in the TableA object it will say "Castle.Proxy" or something along those lines(they when you drill down every property has that error). That's why I expected it to be null or something.Since then I could do a null check on TableB object in TAbleA and not do the query.

Comment: I believe that it says 'Castle.Proxy' etc. since the property is lazy-loaded by default, so perhaps (this is just a guess) nHibernate doesn't know that there's actually no corresponding TableB. then, when you access it with 'TableA.TableB.Id' the TableB object is loaded (and evaluates to null) and then you get a null-reference exception. that actually seems in order. If you try 'if (TableA.TableB == null)' what do you get?

Comment: TableA.TableB(Grade.Course) == null will evaluate to "false"

Comment: It is correct, I agree with sJhonny. When there is no corresponding row in TableA.TableB (Grade.Course) database table then the proxy for TableA.TableB (Grade.Course) property is still created and is not null (but nothing is loaded from database). If you try to access any property in TableA.TableB (Grade.Course) via debugger, then NH tries to load the proxy from database but it fails (no row corresponding with proxy exists) and you will get mentioned exception.